# How can i make a function for a certain textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

This code allows the users to type in certain characters only:

```
let allowedChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-.";
func textField(
    textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
                                  replacementString string: String)
    -> Bool
{
    let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: allowedChars);

    let filtered = string
        .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(set)
        .joinWithSeparator("");
    return filtered != string;

}
```

How can i make it so that it allows a just one textfield called "txtField1"?

Comment: Can you not check that `textfield` as passed into this fucntion matches the textfield you want?  Whether with a tag or just a simple == call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a value to the tag on your textfield that is unique to it (for example, 1).

```
txtField1.tag = 1
```

Then, update your method like this:

```
func textField(
    textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
                                  replacementString string: String)
    -> Bool
{
    if textField.tag == 1 {
        let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: allowedChars)

        let filtered = string
            .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(set)
            .joinWithSeparator("")
        return filtered != string
    }

    return true
}
```

You can also omit the ; in Swift.

Comment: Your final `return` should be `return true`.

Comment: Wont `return` `string` always return `true` "technically?

Comment: @Jeef I doubt Swift will let you even compile that code since `String` is not a `Bool`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether your textField is the one currently selected in your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method because as you can see in the parameters of this method you have access to the property `textField` which correspond to the current textField that you are selecting, so just check this at the beginning :

```
if texField == txtField1 {
  // Do your stuff 
 } else {
 // Do something else 
}
```